# Code Analysis for Visual Studio Code and React-Native

Tags: react-native, android-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

While I am on the learning curve of React-Native, I would like to know if there is an option or plugin in Visual Studio Code equivalent to a tool from IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio:

From VCS -> Commit -> Commit Changes, in this window, there are the following options within the "Before Commit" section:

"Reformat code"

"Rearrange code"

"Optimize imports"

"Perform code analysis"

"Check TODO"

"Cleanup"

"Update copyright"

I already found the "Format Document" and "Source Actions" in Visual Studio Code, but I was wondering if it is possible to have a "Perform Code Analysis" option for the respective elements of React-Native (Or maybe VSC already has something for this but I have not found it yet),

Is there a way to have this option?